# Sending raw data in request body

Tags: java, spring, api, http, netflix-feign

I'm facing the problem with **sending request body as raw text** without quotes.

The content type of request should be *text/uri-list*.

Sending it in Postman works correctly but when I try to implement the same operation in java it does not work.

I'm using feign as api client.

Client definition of endpoint looks like this

```
@RequestLine("PUT /someEndpointOne/{id}/someEndpointTwo")
@Headers("Content-Type: text/uri-list")
JSONObject addSomethingToSomething(@Param("id") String id, @RequestBody okhttp3.RequestBody uri);
```

And I use it in test like this:

```
somethingClient.addSomethingToSomething("1", okhttp3.RequestBody.create(okhttp3.MediaType.parse("text/uri-list"), "http://localhost/someEndpointTwo/1"))
```

Instead of sending raw data it actually sends empty object:

> PUT http://localhost/someEndpointOne/1/someEndpointTwo HTTP/1.1
>
> Content-Type: text/uri-list
>
> Content-Length: 2
>
> **{}**
>
> END HTTP (2-byte body)

what causes bad respone.

I would be grateful for help with solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/someEndpointOne/{id}/someEndpointTwo", headers = "Content-Type=text/uri-list")
JSONObject addSomethingToSomething(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestBody okhttp3.RequestBody uri);
```

Where `@PutMapping` comes from `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping` and `@PathVariable` comes from `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable`.